# Separate Database for each user login in node.js Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

**I am developing an application where I need a separate database for each user.**

So I need to change the database connection on every HTTP Request and use the database of the login user.

I'm Using node.js Sequelize for application development.

## User Database

| id | username | password | database |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | **** | UserDb1 |
| 2 | user2 | **** | UserDb2 |
| 3 | user3 | **** | UserDb3 |
| 4 | user4 | **** | UserDb4 |
| . | ... | **** | ...... |
| n | usern | **** | UserDbn |

## Let's say User1 is making an API request so for that request the database should be UserDb1

How Can I implement the required feature?

Answer (score 1):

you can use multi-tenancy in Squalize

multi-tenancy is an architecture to store the same kind of data in multiple databases

if you have any other doubt, let me know